# How to correctly read 'string' Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

The question I'm aksing isn't about the method of reading a string, more about where to place that string, so that if the game is exportet, you can still read it. Because if you assign a path where a txt-Document with that string is found(C:\Users\User\Desktop\string.txt), it wont be there anymore, if you export the game, for exmple onto another pc.

I've tried using the 'Resources.Load' method, but seems not to be working for strings.

`string st = Resources.Load<string>("AssetsPath)`

So, where or how to save the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot store a string as a resource, I assume you are using a text file as a resource and that you want to load its content. In that case you can use the following code:

```
TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("AssetsPath");
string st = textAsset.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PlayerPrefs` class to save some data.
Here is an example

```cs
PlayerPrefs.SetString("SomeKey", "MyValue");

var myValue = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SomeKey");
```

More on that [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)